# Accessing image from PaintCode in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, paintcode

I'm thinking about buying PaintCode, because I wanna use it in my Swift projects. I downloaded the Trial version. The tutorials at the homepage are only for Objective C, but the explained way (http://www.paintcodeapp.com/documentation/stylekits) doesn't work with Swift.

Any ideas, how I can add the images from PaintCode to my xib file (for example to a toolbar item)? (I have a Cocoa project without Storyboard)

Comment: Which part “doesn’t work” with Swift?

Comment: You can configure PaintCode to 1/ export Images, 2/ generate function that returning `UIImage` or 3/ function drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Paintcode works with Swift you just have to change the output.
You can choose iOS/Obj-c , OSX/iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PaintCode works well with Swift. You only have to select the output as pointed by a comment before and export StyleKit to your project.